# how to pass two columns values to plot line chart in C# interop

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, com-interop, excel-interop

I am trying to plot line chart after generating excel file using Microsoft interop.
**Let my column A is Date, B is Rate and column C is volume and I want to print a chart between Volume and Date.**

I am using this code to plot line chart.

```
var charts = worKsheeT.ChartObjects();
var chartObject = charts.Add(60, 10, 300, 300);
var chart = chartObject.Chart;
var range = worKsheeT.get_Range("C1", "C9");
chart.SetSourceData(range);
 chart.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlChartType.xlLine;
```

But it is giving me a chart which has yAxis as Volume and xAxis is simple 1,2,3,4,5....

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot I got this solution

```
Excel.Series series;
Excel.SeriesCollection seriesCollection;
series = seriesCollection.NewSeries();
var Values = "=Data!$B$2:$B$50";//this is range of columns
var XValues = "=Data!$A$2:$A$50";//this is range of columns
series.Name = "series name";
series.Values = Values;
series.XValues = XValues;
series.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlChartType.xlLine;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another variable:

```
var series = chart.SeriesCollection();
```

Then maybe

```
series[1].XValues = worKsheeT.get_Range("A1", "A9");
```

Remember, C is zero-based, but Excel (even through interop) is one-based.